# How do I reference the cell to the left of the current cell in Google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have to apply a function to every cell in column 2, which retrieves information about a symbol in column 1. I have 100 columns and don't want to individually plug each symbol in, so I need a way to reference the information in A2 in the function being used in B2

E.g.
[This is the spreadsheet I'm working on.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wU38G.png)

=GOOGLEFINANCE(**SymbolDisplayedInTheCellToTheLeftOfThisCell**, "price")

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need a way to reference the information in A2 in the function being used in B2

Just write

`=GOOGLEFINANCE(A2, "price")`

Then select the cells below it and fill down. You could use "select and drag" of 
a combination of keyboard shortcuts:

1. Change the active cell to a cell on the Column A: <kbd>Left arrow</kbd>
2. Go to the last cell: <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Down arrow</kbd>
3. Change the active cell to a cell on the Column B: <kbd>Right arrow</kbd>
4. Select all the cells from the current active cell to the first non-blank cell (B2): <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up arrow</kbd>
5. Fill down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>

This works because A2 is a relative reference. The spreadsheet engine will automatically update the references when making a copy or thousands of copies of the formula.

NOTES:

- GOOGLEFINANCE doesn't work with ARRAYFORMULA
- Another alternative is to write a script, but the above procedure performance / learning curve is faster than Google Apps Script.

Answer (score 23):

While Ruben's answer is better for most calculation (and copy-paste should do the change for you). To get the cell to the left you can use [`ADDRESS` function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093308?hl=en#) and [`ROW`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316?hl=en&ref_topic=3105472&sjid=5190254615618852625-EU) and [`COLUMN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093373?hl=en&ref_topic=3105472&sjid=5190254615618852625-EU)

If you write `=ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN()-1, 4)` on B4 for example, it will return A4

Then you can use `INDIRECT` to get the value in that cell

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. 
This is the function that worked;
=(GOOGLEFINANCE(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN()-1, 4)), "price"))

Comment: Note that this is heavy compute compared to the simple copy/paste

Comment: This is great, we use it to push entries to Google Sheets via an API (Custom Webhook in Zapier) and since hardcoding a cell reference value (e.g. B3) won't work because we don't know which row it will be in, this solves our problem. In our request in JSON format we just send it in string format: "=IMAGE(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN()+1, 4)))" and Google Sheets resolves it. In this particular case, this displays an image and gets the image URL from the cell right to it.

Answer (score 9):

This is an old question, but if somebody needs it ....

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE(INDIRECT("RC[-1]",FALSE), "price")
```

The value on the left cell is obtained by

```
INDIRECT("RC[-1]",FALSE)
```